# How to stub class property

Tags: javascript, sinon

I am trying to Stub class property using sinon.

```
function wrapper() {
  this.obj = {"message":"hello"};
  this.sendmessege = function() {
    console.log(this.obj.message);
    return "message is:" + this.obj.message;
  } 
 }

// stub

var wrap = new wrapper();
stub = sinon.stub(wrap , 'sendmessege', function () { 
    return 'hola'; 
 });
 stub1 = sinon.stub(wrap , {'obj':
   {'message':'hii'}
 });

console.log(stub1);
```

its giving me

> error : Attempted to wrap object property obj as function.

how i can stub obj ?

Comment: Try `sinon.stub(wrap, 'obj', {'message': 'hii'})`

Comment: @NimrodArgov giving Error  'Custom stub should be function'

Comment: I think this feature might only work under the sandbox. You can stub it manually, though.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to stub the property of an object, use the `value()` method of the `Stub`.

```
stub1 = sinon.stub(wrap, 'obj').value({message: 'hii'});
```

---

Documentation Reference: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.2/stubs/#stubvaluenewval

Comment: the link is dead